# Reporting Services repeated header on new page overlaps footer row

Tags: reporting-services

Has anyone had this issue? Does anyone have a work around for this issue?

When the table header is set to **ReapetOnNewPage = true** and then the page breaks right on the last detail row, so the only thing left to display is the footer with the Totals: row, the header overlaps the footer row so it can not be displayed. 

If the page breaks before the footer, it will do it correctly and on the next page will print the detail row then the footer row. But if only the footer is pushed to the next page, the repeated header covers it. 

I know its being covered, because the border for the footer shows through on the edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed with SSRS 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an extra blank footer row above your actual footer so that the header wouldn't overlap, but I'm afraid that may not look right when everything actually works as planned.

Comment: That might work if I could somehow figure out where the page break would be. Then I could only add the extra space as needed.